# How can I invoke a different constructor from a constructor in c#?

Tags: c#

I have the following class

```
public class ReportDataSource : IReportDataSource
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public string Schema { get; set; }
    public string Server { get; set; }

    public ReportDataSource()
    {
    }

    public ReportDataSource(ReportObject obj)
    {
        this.Name = obj.Name;
        this.Alias = obj.Alias;
        this.Schema = obj.Schema;
        this.Server = obj.Server;
    }

    public ReportDataSource(ReportObject obj, string alias)
    {
        this.Name = obj.Name;
        this.Schema = obj.Schema;
        this.Server = obj.Server;

        this.Alias = alias;
    }

}
```

In constructor `ReportDataSource(ReportObject obj, string alias)` behaves exactly as the `ReportDataSource(ReportObject obj)`. The only different is that I can override the `alias` property.

Is there a way I can call `ReportDataSource(ReportObject obj)` from inside `ReportDataSource(ReportObject obj, string alias)` so I won't have to duplicate my code?

I tried this

```
    public ReportDataSource(ReportObject obj, string alias)
        :base(obj)
    {
        this.Alias = alias;
    }
```

but I get this error

> 'object' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

How can I call a different constructor from with in a constructor in c#?

Answer (score 2):

Try `this`:

```
public ReportDataSource(ReportObject obj, string alias)
    :this(obj)
{
    this.Alias = alias;
}
```

It is sometimes called *constructor chaining*.

> An instance constructor initializer of the form **this(***argument-list*<sub>*opt*</sub>**)** causes an instance constructor from the class itself to be invoked. The constructor is selected using *argument-list* and the overload resolution rules of §7.5.3.

Comment: That worked! thank you. I'll accept your answer when time permits